# Plotly.js subplots title on top of trace

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

I'm trying to put only the titles of the subplots on top, but it takes the labels to the top too. Is there any way to have the title on top and the labels on the bottom.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/juanv911/pen/jReyWy

```
xaxis:{
  title:'Nitrogen',
  side:'top',
  tickfont: {size: 8,color: '#222'}, 
  tickangle:'-45',
  showgrid:false, 
}
```

[image: subplots title]

Comment: As far as I know axis title and ticks move together. You could try to use `annotations`.

Comment: Thanks Maximilian, it is a nice workaround